# How can I create a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink, fragment

I am making the link generator right now. First of all, I am creating the link then I send the link to my friend but he can't click the link because of empty characters and another thing. But if you copy the whole of the message string that I send you and paste the address bar in the browser you can reach the link. Because the browser can handle the space and empty characters. I am trying to find a solution I have to make this manipulation before that browser thus my friend can easily click the link and go to the page. Otherwise, I said before he needs to copy whole the link and paste it to the browser I don't wanna happen.

this is the link that I send to my friend (FOCUS THE LAST WORD)

"**[https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation-instructions:~:text=Node.js%20v14.x%3A#:~:text=Node.js](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation-instructions:%7E:text=Node.js%20v14.x%3A#:%7E:text=Node.js) v14.x:**"

but I want to transform this to this

" **[https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation-instructions:~:text=Node.js%20v14.x%3A#:~:text=Node.js%20v14.x:](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation-instructions:%7E:text=Node.js%20v14.x%3A#:%7E:text=Node.js%20v14.x:)** "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can so something like this:

```
function link(str) {
  return str.split(" ").join("%20");
}
```

This will replace all `empty spaces` with `%20` and return the modified link.

---

Check it in action below:

```js
function link(str) {
  return str.split(" ").join("%20");
}

console.log(link("https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation-instructions:~:text=Node.js%20v14.x%3A#:~:text=Node.js v14.x:"));
```